# undefined method `skip_before_action' when skipping authentication in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using this guide for setting up Devise in Rails:
http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles-devise-rails_admin-cancancan/

It says to place this on your home controller to keep Devise from requesting authentication on your home page:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]
```

My home controller is called dev so my dev_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class DevController < ApplicationController
  def index

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]

  end
end
```

Now when I visit my website, I get this error:

```
undefined method `before_action' for #<MenuController:0xb193b640>
```

Any ideas on why I get this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the below

`skip_before_action` is should be out side of the `index` method scope. As `before_action` or `skip_before_action` is a class method. Should not call it inside in an instance method(index)

```
class DevController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]

  def index
  end
end
```

Please [refer](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_action)

Answer (score 2):

As `skip_before_action` is a Class method, it can't be called from instance method.
It's also known as callback method, [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) are other methods.

You can update code as,

```
class DevController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]

  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answer offers anything in addition to the one posted 9 hours earlier?

Answer (score 0):

If `skip_before_action` seems to be confusing you can use `before_action` like below

```
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except:[index]
```